# Exiting a Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that crawls through a website and download all the videos it has. I'm facing a problem that the number of threads continuously increases even after the downloading of individual videos are done.

Here is the code for the individual Worker object, which is queued and then joined later. This is the only part of the code at which I generate a Thread. What I don't understand is how there can be remaining threads if given the object, I implement the `self.stop()` function and the while loop breaks.

```
class Worker(Thread):
def __init__(self, thread_pool):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.tasks = thread_pool.tasks
    self.tasks_info = thread_pool.tasks_info
    self.daemon = True
    self._is_running=True

    self.start()        
def stop(self):
    self._is_running = False
def run(self):
    while self._is_running:
        func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
        try: func(*args, **kargs)
        except Exception:
            print("\nError: Threadpool error.")
            sys.exit(1)

        self.tasks_info['num_tasks_complete'] += 1            
        self.tasks.task_done()
        self.stop()
```

I've used the thread functions to check which threads are alive, and it turns out that it is indeed mostly the worker functions as well as other objects called `Thread(SockThread)` and `_MainThread`, which I do not know how to close.

Please advise on 1. why the Worker thread is not ending and 2. how to get rid of the `Thread(SockThread)` as well as the `_MainThread`.

Thank you!

edit 1

```
class ThreadPool:
def __init__(self, name, num_threads, num_tasks):

    self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)

    self.num_threads=num_threads
    self.tasks_info = {
        'name': name,
        'num_tasks': num_tasks,
        'num_tasks_complete': 0
    }
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        Worker(self)
    print(threading.active_count)


def add_task(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    self.tasks.put((func, args, kwargs))
def wait_completion(self):
    print("at the beginning of wait_completion:")
    print(threading.active_count())
```

Comment: You do not want to get rid of `_MainThread`. That is, as its name suggests, the `_MainThread` launched by the interpreter. It's pretty hard to guess why the thread isn't stopping without knowing what `func` actually does. Also it would be useful to know how you are creating worker threads.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I had to keep that thread. Thank you. Can you check the edit 1 for the code on how the worker threads are created?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` (both of which are based on threads, not separate processes)?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code it looks like you have initialized the thread which calls the `run()` method for processing. After that you're even using the start method which is not the proper way. Your code should be as follows:

```
from threading import Event
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_pool):
       self.tasks = thread_pool.tasks
       self.tasks_info = thread_pool.tasks_info
       self.exit = Event()
       super(Thread,self).__init__()

   def shutdown(self):
       self.exit.set()

   def run(self):
       while not self.exit.is_set():
          func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
          try: 
              func(*args, **kargs)
          except Exception:
              print("\nError: Threadpool error.")
              # use shutdown method for error
              self.shutdown()
              sys.exit(1)

          self.tasks_info['num_tasks_complete'] += 1            
          self.tasks.task_done()
          self.shutdown()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried doing this and the entire code stops working(it doesn't raise an error, it just stops) at the .join() method for the queue at which the operations(things to do?) are queued. Why would this be?

Comment: It would be gud if I know what ua function does? May be we r calling shutdown inside the while loop is stopping the thread.try using the shutdown wen u want the program to be exited.